# How do I run a subset of spock functional tests in grails?

Tags: grails, tags, functional-testing, spock, geb

In some other testing frameworks I'm used to tagging tests, eg @really_slow, @front_end

And then running different batches of tests, like I might want to set up a build slave to run all the really_slow tests, and might want to run all the tests tagged as front end but none that are marked  as really slow.

To run my spock+geb tests in grails at the moment I just run grails test-app functional:

How do I tell it to run a subset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use JUnit suites with `@Category`. Or you could use a `SpockConfig.groovy` with the following contents:

```
runner {
    include foo.bar.FrontEnd, foo.bar.BackEnd
    exclude foo.bar.Slow
}
```

Here, `foo.bar.FrontEnd`, `foo.bar.BackEnd`, and `foo.bar.Slow` are your own annotations. To activate the configuration file, you have to set a `spock.configuration` system property pointing to it.

Comment: Great answer, where can I find documentation on the SpockConfig.groovy file?

Comment: It isn't currently well documented. You can find some bits in the Javadoc (e.g. http://javadoc.spockframework.org/latest/spock/config/RunnerConfiguration.html). The default location for the config file is `~/.spock/SpockConfig.groovy`. If necessary, you can set a different file path via the `spock.configuration` system property.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting that to work. I get an error that says the config file is wrong but it doesn't say what line. Is there a command-line way to specify the spock configuration?

Comment: Similar problem, complaining the Spock config file cannot compile, when it should (based on the example and IntelliJ compiling it without issues) `import com.myproject.test.ReadOnly

runner {
    include ReadOnly
}
`

Comment: Apparently this is the reason: https://code.google.com/p/spock/issues/detail?id=184